# How to call a PHP script from a PHP script on another server

Tags: php

I have access to two distinct servers. I would like one's PHP script to call a URL on the other's server (and pass a secret variable). However, I want to make sure nobody else can spoof this call.

What is the best way to do this, short of SSL? I was thinking about hashing but anyone can read the POST request's hash and spoof it.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is SSL not an option?

Comment: Dunno. Don't have any good certificates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need SSH. You call the other script through ssh, which means no one else can see what's going on. See [this blog](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this

- If your servers have static ip's, you could check the IP address. (If you are on shared hosting other people on the server will have the same IP)
- You can encrypt the data with AES and decrypt it on the other end. Of course you'd have to encode this (using [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php), for example) before POST'ing it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using cURL and a SSL connection?

Comment: The OP asked what was the best way to do this, short of using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to employ some kind of encryption to encrypt the variable. RSA is a secure, common one that has [examples ready](http://www.example-code.com/php/rsa.asp) to copy/paste in php. It might be a bit hard to wrap your head around, but once you get it working, it is extremely secure.

Honestly your easiest way is SSL encryption.

Comment: RSA is not only broken but also very inefficient. Why use asymmetric encryption when you can use symmetric?

Comment: @NullUserException: I agree that in this case, symmetric encryption is a good option. However, I'm curious about RSA being broken - are you referring the to University of Michigan exploit which introduces voltage fluctutations into the CPU of the server holding the private key?

Comment: @Mike "Textbook" RSA has been proven insecure for a while now. Regardless, RSA's recommended key size is 2048bits vs AES' 256-bit. Not only you have a much bigger key, but it takes a lot more time to compute.

Comment: @NullUserException: I'm not disputing that asymmetric crptography is slower than symmetric crptography - that's why RSA is usually only used to encrypt keys for use in symmetric crptography. I was just curious about the details of the RSA exploit.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that is possible at all. If the PHP-Script of ServerA calls the script on ServerB, that script will be interpreted by ServerB, it generates an output HTML/Whatever and gives that output to the script of ServerA.

AFAIK it's not possible to access a PHP-Script before it is interpreted, as long as you don't have direct FTP-Access on it.